# Am having a datetime parameter in DD-MM-YYYY format in SSRS how to change the format of datetime parameter to DD-MMM-YYYY

Tags: sql-server, datetime, reporting-services

Am new to Reporting Services and currently am facing issue in formatting the datetime parameter
Currently my report is displaying the time as `DD-MM-YYYY` i am trying to display the datetime format as `DD-MMM-YYYY` and i tired using the expression

```
=DateTime.Parse(Format(Now,"dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm"))
```

still am getting it as `22-12-2015 09:47:00`, am not getting where am missing in parameter setting,

Comment: I think you need to change your expression to `Format(Now,"dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm")` - As you have mentioned that you want the datetime format `DD-MMM-YYYY `

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime.Parse` is *undoing* your formatting - it parses your nicely formatted `DateTime`-`String` back into a `DateTime`.

Just remove it and use

```
=Format(Now,"dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm")
```

Answer (score 0):

select CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),GETDATE(),113)
 try this answer will be like this

```
 22 Dec 2015 10:27:18:463
```